# how to use bulk API to insert null value in date format to elasticsearch

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

in elasticsearch,I have a date field setup in my mapping like this:

```
"create_time" : {
 "type" : "date",
 "null_value" : "NULL"
 },
```

i use pandas to process my data,it like this:

```
    create_date
0       NULL
1       2019-09-23 14:32:32.217377
```

and in python i use bulk API,the method is:

```
def gendata(data, index):
    INDEX = index
    TYPE = "doc"
    for record in data:
        yield {
            "_index": INDEX,
            "_type": TYPE,
            "_source": record,
        }
bulk(client,gendata(data.to_dict(orient="records"),index="test"))
```

> but i get BulkIndexError:('1 document(s) failed to index.', [{'index':
>   {'_index': 'ics_asset', '_type': 'doc', '_id': '85vaXG0Be27aFy3eNkCZ',
>   'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception',
>   'reason': 'mapper [create_date] of different type, current_type
>   [date], merged_type [text]'}, 'data': {'create_date': 'null'}}}]).

how can i use pandas bulk right "null" value with date format to elasticsearch.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation about `null_value`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) clearly states:

> The `null_value` needs to be the same datatype as the field. For instance, a `long` field cannot have a string `null_value`.

This means you cannot assign the string `NULL` as `null_value` for a `date` field.

This `null_value` is only useful if you want to explicitly query documents with no value for a particular field. Maybe you can assign a date like `1900-01-01` so that you can query them with that particular date.

Otherwise, you can drop the `null_value` option and you'll be perfectly able to index documents with a regular `null` value. The only downside is that you won't be able to retrieve documents by `null` create date.